# How can I make the largest number with most numbers of divisors appear in the output?

Tags: python-3.x

Title kinda says it all, how do I make a code where I can make the largest number with most divisors appear in the output?

```
start = int(input("Enter start number: "))

     if start <= 0:
        print("Invalid Input...")

end = int(input("Enter end number: "))

     if end <= 0:

        print("Invalid Input...")

divisor = 0

for i in range (start, end):

     if end% i == 0:
        divisor = i
        divisor //= start

print("{0} has {1} divisor.".format(end, divisor))
```

I expect the output to be like if I input 5 at start and 100 at the end it would look like

```
Enter start number: 5

Enter end number: 100

96 has 10 divisors.
```

But instead of 96 it is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function, that will return number of divisors for selected number. That way you can find a number with maximum count of divisors and print it:

```
start = int(input("Enter start number: "))

if start <= 0:
    print("Invalid Input...")

end = int(input("Enter end number: "))

if end <= 0:
    print("Invalid Input...")

def divisors(n):
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            cnt += 2
    return cnt

current_max, current_cnt = 0, 0
for i in range(start, end):
    n = divisors(i)
    if n >= current_cnt:
        current_cnt = n
        current_max = i

print("{0} has {1} divisor.".format(current_max, current_cnt))
```

Prints (for input `5` and `100`):

```
96 has 10 divisor.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Write a Python program to input 3 numbers and find the largest. Print all the numbers, and the  largest among them, with appropriate titles.  
n1=float(input("Enter number 1: "))
n2=float(input("Enter number 2: "))
n3=float(input("Enter number 3: "))
if n1 > n2 :
 if n1 > n3 :
     LNo=n1
 else :
     LNo=n3
else :
 if n2 >n3 :
     LNo=n2
 else :
     LNo=n3
print("DISPLAY........")
print("Number 1 : ",n1)
print("Number 2 : ",n2)
print("Number 3 : ",n3)
print("Largest number is : ",LNo)
```